# subplot using for loops matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

Hey I cant figure out why my plot line is not showing up in the figure window.  I am using for loops and I believe the syntax is correct but it clearly is not. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

```
%
%Lecture 6
%
%Feb. 16, 2016
%
close all
load lec6
home
figure(1)
plot(x,y)
xlabel('Distance')
ylabel('Height')
axis([0 max(x) 0 max(x)])

thd = atan2(y(2),x(2))*180/pi
dt = (t(2)-t(1))

for count = 1:length(t)-1
    dx(count)=(x(count+1)-x(count))/dt;
    dy(count)=(y(count+1)-y(count))/dt;
end
for count = 1:length(t)-2
    d2y(count)=(dy(count+1)-dy(count))/dt;
end

thd = atan2(y(2),x(2))*180/pi
thr = thd*pi/180
v0 = dt/cos(thr)
figure(2)
hold on
for count = 1:length(t)-1;
    h=t(count)
    j=dx(count)
    plot(h,j)
    axis([0 max(t) 0 max(t)])
end
```

Comment: What is happening and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Daniel right now it is plotting nothing on figure 2, the figure should display a straight line across 65 across the y axis with each point increasing by .1 each time on the x axis.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the `hold on` after `figure(2)`.
  As is, Figure 2 will show the plot for the last index of the loop.

It seems that t is a vector, and so the plot inside the loop will plot one point at a time, and since the default type is a line it might show nothing.

Try removing the for and doing:

```
plot(t,dx)
axis([0 max(t) 0 max(t)])
```

Comment: The dimensions of the t and dx don't match, t is a 1X629 matrix and dx is a 1X628 matrix

Comment: Ah, then do `plot(t(1:end-1),dx)` or `plot(t(2:end),dx)`, whichever makes more sense to you.